# How do I utilize PageViewController, to generate a new page view based on input from the User?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a PageViewController which controls 3 ViewControllers that act as templates, and display information based on the selection of the user, Very similar to the IOS weather app, when adding a new city, it creates a new page. I want to do the exact same, how would i use the PageViewController, to actually create a ViewController so I can then append it based on the selection of the user, rather than having 3 empty ViewControllers waiting for input, as it looks unproffessional having 3 available empty pages, rather than 1 main page with an option to create or add a new page. Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `setViewControllers(_:direction:animated:completion:)` to add viewcontrollers in the pageviewcontroller at runtime.

Ref : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller